# Representation of string as some power of substring

Tags: string, algorithm

Given a string, we have to check if a string can be represented by a substring of it repeated some finite times.

> ababab -> (ab)^3

I saw a solution which says to first find the longest proper prefix which is also a suffix. Let the length of this prefix be some k. Let n be the length of the original string. If n%(n-k) == 0, the string can be represented as a substring repeated finite times. Otherwise,no.

I am not able to understand the logic behind this solution. Can anybody explain me why this solution works?
Link where I saw this solution:[geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-given-string-can-represented-substring-iterating-substring-n-times/)

Comment: Explanation is given there, in link you have given, with diagram too. What better explanation you need?

Comment: I was not able to understand it. I wanted a generalized proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so first, let call the substring that forms `input` string `A`. So,

```
input = A ^ a (with a is constant)
```

We can see that, the longest proper prefix which is also a suffix should cover at least half of the `input` if `input` is a power string. The prove is simple

- If `a` is even, the case is trivial.
- If `a` is odd, so `input = (A^b)A(A^b)`, we can see that, the longest prefix suffix should be at least `(A^b)A (with b = (a - 1)/2)`

So, now, let consider three cases:

- If the length `k` of the prefix suffix is `k < n/2` , so `n - k > n/2` -> `n % (n - k) != 0`, as proved above, this string cannot be a power string.
- If the length `k` of the prefix suffix is `k = n/2` -> this case is trivial.
- If the length `k` of the prefix suffix is `k > n/2`, so, we can visualize the input string as

  ```
  input = ACA
  ```

  With C is the overlapping area between the prefix and suffix, and as prefix and suffix are equaled, we can see that

  ```
  AC = CA
  ```

  Let assume length of `C > A`, in order for `AC = CA`, so , we can divide C into `C = A + B` -> `A + A + B = A + B + A`, this can only happen if `A == B`.

  So, the input will have the form `input = AAAA` which is clearly a power string. 
  In case `C = A`, we have `input = AAA`, and case `C < A` can be proved similar to case `C > A`.

Answer (score 0):

If n%(n-k) == 0, the string can be represented as a substring repeated finite times. Otherwise,no. This statement is very helpful in the algorithm so let's start by proving it 
If n-k is length of the suffix so if n%(n-k) != 0 n will be equal to the concatination of q string with length = n-k and a string with length minor to n-k (q = n / (n-k))
So n in this case can't be the square of the suffix 
Reasoning by opposition lead 
Now let's write the code

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myString = "abab";
            int k = suffixLentgth(myString);
            if (k > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myString.Substring(k, myString.Length - k));
            }

        }
        static int suffixLentgth(string ch)
        {
            int n = ch.Length;
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
            {
                bool isPower = true;
                if (n % (n - i) == 0) // this suffix can fulfil your dreams
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < (n / (n - i)) - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (ch.Substring((n - i) * j, n - i) != ch.Substring((n - i) * (j + 1), n - i))
                        {
                            isPower = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isPower)
                        return i;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```